# Updating A Huge SQLite Database Daily

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Ok, so I'm working on a project where the database will hold about 20000 elements all in one table. Example: I have a store that sells 20000 products and I'd like to update them daily. Only about 100-200 will be updated daily.

I was thinking of doing the whole database native so it would be faster. I'd like to know if that is good way to get into the problem or should I use any other mean of saving and showing the data? I'm worried that update files would be too huge for daily download/update.

Is it possible to update a database due to the fact that everytime you update the database it builds itself from 0?

Excuse my grammar. Jan

Comment: Did you investigate content provider? It's pretty useful once you get used to working on cursors in the application. It also enables you to build your application around uris (e.g. open an item via it's id like content://product/id). It also works nice with cursor loaders and automatically refreshing data adapters on database changes.

Comment: 20k elements is still okay, but if you have images etc for each, the amount of data is getting really big. I don't know if it makes sense to have all that locally on each device that wants to use the store. You need an online connection to buy things so you could just implement a nicer way to browse the online store. Updating data is a lot simpler that way and users don't need to update the complete store when they just want to check a single item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to update database. You need to update **database content**. Let's your app store any kind of identifier (let say int). Each day you release update to your database **content** - only diff from content from previous day. Your app should then check what is current id of database on the server and then fetch and apply all the differences between id that db contains and recent version. Or build one update file on request knowing what revision of content customer have and what is recent. If users use your app daily then it will be no big deal.

> s it possible to update a database due to the fact that everytime you update the database it builds itself from 0?

Then you most likely do this a bit wrong. You need to be able to build incrementally (or at least you should always be able to assign the same ID to i.e. the same product from the DB).

Or if final database dump is small (i.e. 5MB-50MB-500MB - you name it). Just let your app fetch whole DB file and replace old content without wasting time and efforts for incremental updates as handling of these can cost more time/money than replacing whole DB.

Comment: Thank you very much, another thing I'd like to know if there is possible that updating would be in the background without users knowledge. So let's say every day at 7pm app would check if there is a new version and if it would update it?

Comment: Yes, no problem. You use AlarmManager to set event at certain hour, and once AM wake you app you spawn AsyncTask or IntentService to do the job